# Unable to Return jSon string from WCF Service from jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, wcf, jsonp

I am having some WCF Services which returns a JSON String. 
The URL for it is, http://localhost:50377/DailyNote/AggregationService/PnlByBookName/{DailyPnl}/Book?bookName={Oil}&buisinessDay={03/02/2011}

Now I want to get this string in HTML using jQuery. The javascript is:

```
var Type; var Url; var Data; var ContentType; var DataType; var ProcessData; var method;
function CallService() {
    $.ajax({                
        type: Type, 
        url: Url,                     
        data: "bookName=Oil&buisinessDay=02032012", 
        contentType: ContentType, 
        dataType: DataType, 
        processdata: ProcessData, 
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("service success");
            ServiceSucceeded(msg);
        },
        error: ServiceFailed
    });        
}

function ServiceFailed(xhr) { 
    alert("service fail: " + xhr.status + " : " + xhr.statusText);
    alert(xhr.responseText);
    if (xhr.responseText) {
        var err = xhr.responseText;if (err) error(err); else error({ Message: "Unknown      server error." });
    } return; 
}

function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
    alert("Service Success");
    if (DataType == "jsonp") {
        resultObject = result.GetPnlByBookHierarchy;
        alert(resultObject);
    }
}

function GetData() {
    Type = "GET";
    Url = "http://localhost:50377/DailyNote/AggregationService/PnlByBookName/DailyPnl/Book?";
    DataType = "jsonp";
    ProcessData = true; 
    method = "PnlByBookName";
    ContentType = "application/javascript"; 
    CallService(); 
}

$(document).ready(function () {            
    GetData();            
});
```

On execution, the alert form the Service Failed is Triggered with xhr.status as 200 & xhr.statusText as Success. 
I am able to call the Service but am unable to receive the jSon back.

Comment: Try to use  {"bookName":"Oil","buisinessDay":"02/03/2012"} instead of "bookName=Oil&buisinessDay=02032012"....when passing data to ajax request.

Comment: Have you checked that the JSON being returned is actually valid?

Comment: Yes I tried, {"bookName":"Oil","buisinessDay":"02/03/2012"}But that does not work.

Comment: The Web Service does returns a valid JSON String.

Answer (score 0):

If port or host are not same domain service has to return JSONP or you will need to proxy the request

Comment: They are both in the same ports.

Comment: in that case you don't want jsonp datatype, just json